# how to stop value rendering in another component of same file?

Tags: lightning-web-components

when i click the button its value is showing in

{entreeQuantity}

tag but at the same time value is showing in another component rendered using for loop

**entrees.html**

```
<template >
        <lightning-card title="Entrees">
            <lightning-layout>
                <template if:true={entrees}>
                    <template for:each={entrees} for:item="entree">
                        <lightning-layout-item key={entree.id}>
                            <lightning-card title={entree.Name}>
                                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap ">
                                    <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={entree.entree_Image__c}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
                                    <p class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">{entree.Name}</p>
                                    <div class="slds-grid">
                                        <lightning-button title="add" icon-name="utility:add" onclick={addEntree}></lightning-button>
                                        <p>{entreeQuantity}</p>
                                        <lightning-button title="remove" icon-name="utility:dash" onclick={removeEntree}></lightning-button>
                                        <lightning-button label="Add" title="Add"></lightning-button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                            </lightning-card>
                        </lightning-layout-item>
                    </template>
                </template>
                <template if:true={error}>
                    error occured during loading card
                </template>
            
        </lightning-layout>
        </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**entrees.js**

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';
import getEntrees from '@salesforce/apex/Entrees.getEntrees';
export default class Entrees extends LightningElement {
    entrees;
    error;
    entreeQuantity = 0;
    connectedCallback(){
        getEntrees()
        .then(result =>{
            this.entrees = result;
            console.log("entrees",JSON.stringify(this.entrees));
        }).catch(error =>{
            this.error = error;
        })
        
    }
    addEntree()  {
        if (this.entreeQuantity < 10) {
            this.entreeQuantity += 1;
            console.log(this.entreeQuantity); 
        }
    }
    removeEntree() {
        if (this.entreeQuantity > 0) {
            this.entreeQuantity -= 1;
            console.log(this.entreeQuantity);
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the other component?

Comment: Actually not other component but In above "entrees.js" 3 records are loading from APEX class and  I am showing that records using this "<template for:each={entrees} for:item="entree">" loop and I have created two buttons for each record when i click on "add" button of one record its value is showin in "<p>{entreeQuantity}</p>" tag but at the same time that value is showing in "<p>{entreeQuantity}</p>" of other records.

Comment: I think you just answered on your question because entreeQuantity attribute won't be unique for each iterated item, it will be always the same because it's just a single attribute wich you're referencing for each record.

Comment: how to keep it unique?

Comment: it's better to decide the best way on what you're going to do with this value in future. Save to the record or just display it?